# Multiple and long entry in xfce4-panel.xml for mpris-players

Tags: xubuntu, firefox, pulseaudio, xfce, chromium

Xubuntu 22.04/xfce.

I noticed a very long entry in the xfce4 panel configuration file `xfce4-panel.xml` (`~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/`), for plugin "pulseaudio":

```
<property name="plugin-10" type="string" value="pulseaudio">
  <property name="enable-keyboard-shortcuts" type="bool" value="true"/>
  <property name="enable-mpris" type="bool" value="true"/>
  <property name="mixer-command" type="string" value="pavucontrol"/>
  <property name="mpris-players" type="string" value="brave.instance179309;chromium.instance10173;chromium.instance10510;chromium.instance10607;chromium.instance10818;chromium.instance10881; ... chromium.instance9879;firefox.instance10260;firefox.instance10801 ... firefox.instance9880;parole;vlc.instance3789"/>
```

"Chromium.instanceXXX" repeats 328 times and "firefox.instanceXXX" repeats 135 times.

It seems that this only applies to entries for firefox and chromium browsers.
In catalog `xubuntu-default-settings: /etc/xdg/xdg-xubuntu/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/` there is no file `xfce4-panel.xml`.

Where to look for the source file and what could be causing this problem?

Regards

P.S.
I forgot to add:
Deleting the entry with `xfce4-settings-editor` does not solve the problem.
After a few days, the value increases again.